# How to add select all for each column separately in dynamic table angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have designed dynamic input matrix table. In that need to add select all option for each column. How to do that?

Here code:

```
<table [ngClass]="{'isDisplay': hasACLAccess}" class="responsive-table-input-matrix" id="matrixTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>  
            <th>Features/Roles</th>
            <th *ngFor="let column of TableConfiguration.columns;">
                {{column.title}}
            <th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor=" let feature of featureNameList">
        <tr>
            <td>{{feature.name}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let a of feature.roles">
            <input name="access" [(ngModel)]="a.access" type="checkbox" 
                (change)="accessArrayList($event)">
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

In this, if checkbox of HR checked, then all checkboxes belongs to HR column should select, likewise for unchecked state also.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What do you mean by "In that need to add select all option for each column."? No matter what checkbox I click all get selected? Or one main checkbox that selects all sub-checkboxes?

Comment: If main checkbox get seleccted, then that sub checkbox of particular column need to be in checked state

Comment: can you provide some mockups with desired result?

Comment: I have edited the post. Please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all checkbox in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933583/how-to-select-all-checkbox-in-angular-2)